# How would you go about long conditional proofs?

Tags: logic

So, I've had problems similar to this, but this problem is way larger than I'm used to, and I'm not sure how to go about this. What do I assume? I want to assume $p \land q$, but then what?

Show  the  following  using  conditional  proof.    You  may  assume  associativity  and commutativity,  and  you  may  use  generalized  forms  of  laws  and  rules. Justify  each  step,  but you need not show the substitutions used in applying laws and rules.

$$p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u \vdash p \land q \to (\lnot r \lor s \to t \land u)$$

Comment: Does the symbol "^" represent "$\land$"?

Comment: Yes. ^ = and, v = or.

Comment: Then if you assume $p\land q$, that gives you the truth of _both_ $p$ and $q$. You can use those with your hypothesis to get more things. For example, since $q$ is true, $\lnot q$ is false, hence $r$ is true.

Comment: I don't follow Quasi. I'm not sure how knowing ¬q being false helps. I've went down this route, and got stuck.

Comment: Where in the hypothesis do you see $\lnot q$? Your hypothesis has 3 distinct statements, separated by commas. Which one involves $\lnot q$? Any statement in the hypothesis is assumed to be true.

Comment: I think moreso, I got to the exact point you bring up. I found r to be true. Past that? I had nothing. I have 4 more of these to do, so a full solve would help greatly so I can analyze how it's done.

Comment: Sorry, you can do this. Try harder. Now that you know $r$ is true, you have $p,q,r$ are all true. That gives you what new instant result?

Comment: Um. What? How? I don't see it. Where do you get that step? And then how would I get that all to make ¬r∨s→t∧u? It doesn't click. Hence, why I need to see the whole thing.

Comment: If $p,q,r$ are true, then $u$ is true (_instantly_).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55877/discussion-between-xenorosth-and-quasi).

Comment: In any case, I tried to help a little, but I don't have time to write a full solution. Maybe someone else can help a little more. Good luck.

Comment: What (axiom) system do you use? Can you use the deduction theorem for example?

Comment: In short, it's using "inference rules". IE, disjunctive syllogism, modus ponnens, ect.

Comment: Like all these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_inference ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.In short, from quasi's comments, I'm trying to figure out how you get p, q, and r is found.

Comment: One of the rules you are going to want to use is $a, \lnot a \lor b \vdash b$ a couple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're allowed to use the deduction theorem that is you're almost done if you can prove:
$$p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q \vdash \lnot r \lor s \to t \land u$$
and that is almost done if you prove 
$$p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q, \lnot r \lor s \vdash t \land u$$

What we want to use is the fact that $\neg\phi\lor\psi$ is the same ase $\phi\rightarrow\psi$, that way we get that from the assumptions that we know that both $p$ and $q$ (from $p\land q$) which via implications leads to $t$ and $u$. The rest is to put this into symbolics, first we deduce $t$:

$$\begin{align}
\tag{1}p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q, \lnot r \lor s & \vdash p\land q & \text{premise}\\
\tag{2}p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q, \lnot r \lor s & \vdash p &\text{conjunction elimination form (1)}\\
\tag{3}p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q, \lnot r \lor s & \vdash p \to (s\to t)&\text{premise}\\
\tag{4}p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q, \lnot r \lor s & \vdash s \to t&\text{modus ponens using (2) and (3)}\\
\tag{5}p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q, \lnot r \lor s & \vdash q &\text{conjunction elimination using (2)}\\
\tag{6}p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q, \lnot r \lor s & \vdash \neg\neg q&\text{double negation using (5)}\\
\tag{7}p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q, \lnot r \lor s & \vdash \neg q\lor r&\text{premise}\\
\tag{8}p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q, \lnot r \lor s & \vdash r&\text{disjunctive syllogism using (6) and (7)}\\
\tag{9}p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q, \lnot r \lor s & \vdash \neg\neg r&\text{double negation}\\
\tag{10}p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q, \lnot r \lor s & \vdash \neg r\lor s&\text{premise}\\
\tag{11}p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q, \lnot r \lor s & \vdash s&\text{disjunctive syllogism using (9) and (10)}\\
\tag{12}p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q, \lnot r \lor s & \vdash t&\text{modus ponens using (11) and (4)}\\
\end{align}$$

We can also stright forwardly deduce $u$:

$$
\begin{align}
\tag{13}p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q, \lnot r \lor s & \vdash p&\text{repetition of (2)}\\
\tag{14}p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q, \lnot r \lor s & \vdash q&\text{repetition of (5)}\\
\tag{15}p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q, \lnot r \lor s & \vdash r&\text{repetition of (8)}\\
\tag{16}p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q, \lnot r \lor s & \vdash (p\land q\land r)&\text{conjunction introuduction using (13), (14) and (15)}\\
\tag{17}p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q, \lnot r \lor s & \vdash (p\land q\land r)\to u&\text{premise}\\
\tag{18}p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q, \lnot r \lor s & \vdash u&\text{modus ponens using (16) and (17)}\\
\end{align}
$$

Now we only have to wrap it up using the deduction theorem.

$$
\begin{align}
\tag{19}p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q, \lnot r \lor s & \vdash u \land v&\text{conjunction introduction using (12) and (18)}\\
\tag{20}p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u, p \land q &\vdash \lnot r \lor s \to u \land v&\text{deduction theorem using (19)}\\
p \to (s \to t), \lnot q \lor r, p\land q \land r \to u &\vdash p \land q \to (\lnot r \lor s \to u \land v)&\text{deduction theorem using (20)}\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I'll add comments to the steps...

Comment: ¬ϕ ψ I'm not sure what both of these symbols are. The steps I use are much simple looking than this. D:

Comment: @Xenorosth $\phi$ and $\psi$ hose are just arbitrary statements (to be replaced with $q$ and $r$ respectively $r$ and $s$). It's just to explain where I'm going, I'm using $q\to r$ and $r\to s$, but that's basically disjunctive syllogism.

Answer (score 0):

The sought conclusion:

> $p∧q→(¬r∨s→t∧u)$

is a *conditional*; thus, the "strategy" is to assume the *antecedent* and use it to "unpack" the premises:

1) $p \land q$ --- assumed [a].

From it, by $\land$E, we derive the *conjuncts* :$p$ and $q$ and then we can use $p$ to derive:

2) $s→t$ --- from 1st premise: $p→(s→t)$ and 1) by $\to$E.

But also the *consequent* of the sought conclusion is a conditional: $¬r∨s → t∧u$ and we need some of its "components" to go on. So, new assumption:

3) $¬r∨s$ --- assumed [b].

It is a *disjunction*, and thus we have to use $\lor$E (*proof by cases*).

First case (outer $\lor$E):

4) $s$ --- assumed [c] for $\lor$E.

5) $t$ --- from 2) and 4) by $\to$E.

Now use $\lor$E again with 2nd premise: $¬q∨r$.

First case (inner $\lor$E)

6) $r$ --- assumed [d] for $\lor$E.

7) $p \land q \land r$ --- from 1) and 6) by $\land$I

8) $u$ --- from 3rd premise: $p∧q∧r → u$ and 7) by $\to$E

9) $t∧u$ --- from 5) and 8) by $\land$I.

One "path" has been completed; now we have to do the same for all others "open path" due to the two nested $\lor$E, in order to derive $t \land u$ in all cases.

Having done that, we go on with:

10) $(¬r∨s) \to (t∧u)$ --- from 3) and 9) by $\to$I (*Conditional Proof*), discharging [b]

> 11) $p∧q→(¬r∨s→t∧u)$ --- from 1) and 10) by $\to$I (*Conditional Proof*), discharging [a].